# Open source system not work on my server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I downloaded [e-Svaasthya](http://sourceforge.net/projects/esvaasthya) but it does not work on my server. Please see the below errors and offer your advice to run this system on my server:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\Installer.php on
>   line 107
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\Installer.php on
>   line 120
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb.inc.php
>   on line 857
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb.inc.php
>   on line 863
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb.inc.php
>   on line 1170
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb.inc.php
>   on line 1935
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb.inc.php
>   on line 2955
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb.inc.php
>   on line 3481
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb.inc.php
>   on line 3521
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb.inc.php
>   on line 3540
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php
>   on line 355
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of dbTable::create() should be
>   compatible with dbObject::create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php
>   on line 570
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of dbIndex::create() should be
>   compatible with dbObject::create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php
>   on line 734
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of dbQuerySet::create() should be
>   compatible with dbObject::create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\classes\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php
>   on line 996
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of SQLFile::getHTML() should be
>   compatible with BaseAction::getHTML() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\actions\SQLFile.php
>   on line 240
>
> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\Installer.php on
>   line 89
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Installer::getTestPath() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pacs_core\e-Svaasthya-0.1\installer\includes\Version.php
>   on line 34

Comment: Fortuitously, we can work out what software you are running from your error message, but we should not have to guess. You should also say which version of PHP you are running, and what you have done to try fixing this. What are the system requirements noted in the docs? Have you done some web research?

Comment: Thanks halfer , im not good in php im still learning php & mysql now im using dreamweaver to write the code and Apache server3.1.0 .. iv project on health care so i want full open source code then i work on it and update it until i reach what i want

Comment: Apache is only up to 2.4.6, so that version number is wrong. What version of PHP are you running? It will start with a 5.

Comment: hi halfer this problem solved i contact the company and they cave me upgrade so now there is no problem .. thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

e-Svaasthya is apparently not optimized for the PHP 5.4. You can contact the creators for suggestions/patches/newer version, or use PHP 5.3.